# What is the expected match if more than one rows match on a join condition performing an update operation in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider a query of this sort:

```
UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = table2.attr1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.attr3 = table2.attr3
```

Supposing there are duplicate attr3s in table2 and hence more than one rows that have a match with one single row of attr3 in table1, which row's attr1 will be assigned as table1's attr1?

I tried using an order by expecting that it will pick up the first match but I see that different matches are being picked up in different instances. Please let me know if I should add a sample data set if I did not make the scenario clear.

Comment: Please add sample scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always helps to read [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html#AEN82098):

> *In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, **but which one will be used is not readily predictable***

(emphasis mine)

So the anwer to your question is: it's unpredictable